# Logs in a separate database: would CiviCRM hangs if Logs database got corrupted?

Tags: mysql, logs

Well, subject has pretty much all of the question. Anyone with firsthand experience please?

Answer (score 2):

Logs in a separate database is fine.  It's what we do at Veda to make the databases more portable and easier to backup.

Before CiviCRM 5.16, the log tables were in Archive format, which is prone to corruption. Starting with CiviCRM 5.16 the logs are in InnoDB format - but remain in Archive format if logging was already enabled.  If possible, switch the log tables to InnoDB format using the [InnoDB Logging](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.innodbtriggers) extension.

If you can't (size of the log tables will grow, especially when indexes are added) then yes, if the tables become corrupt the database transactions will fail but this is the same regardless of if the log tables are in the same schema or not.

Hope that helps